# Javascript does not print text immediately

Tags: javascript

I wrote this code which is supposed to say "hi" when I click the "hello" button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<script>
var someLargeNumber = 5000000000;
function hello() {
    document.getElementById('hi').innerHTML = "hi";
    for(var i = 0; i < someLargeNumber; i++) {}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="hi"></p>
<input type="button" value="hello" onclick="hello();">
</body>

</html>
```

It does say hi, but only after the `for` loop is finished. Why does this happen and how do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could take out the loop. Why is it there?  The browser won't (necessarily) re-render the page until the "click" handler is finished.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Why does this happen...

Because browsers run JavaScript on the main UI thread they use for updating the page, for a variety of reasons. So although you've shown the "hi" text, it doesn't get rendered until the JavaScript code running in response to the event completes.

> ...and how do I fix this?

Yield back to the browser after adding the text, before doing whatever it is that you're simulating with that loop. `setTimeout` with a delay of `0` is suitable for many cases:

```
var someLargeNumber = 5000000000;
function hello() {
    document.getElementById('hi').innerHTML = "hi";
    setTimeout(function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < someLargeNumber; i++) {}
    }, 0);
}
```

The JavaScript engine works basically in a loop with a task queue (the spec calls them "jobs"). It picks up a job from the queue, runs it to completion, and then looks for the next job. Browsers (usually) update the UI when the engine is between jobs. When an event occurs, a job is queued to call the event handler. The above just moves the loop into a new job it queues via `setTimeout`, so the browser has a chance after the event job and before the `setTimeout` job to update the UI.

Comment: [Related question/answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful) dedicated to the `setTimeout(fn,0);` pattern

Answer (score 0):

As already answered browser has single UI thread.

Another option is to use `Web Worker` (provided you are not doing any DOM manipulations in the worker thread), which allows to run operations in an another thread.

Add another js file (say worker.js)

```
var someLargeNumber = 5000000000;
onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log('Message received from main script');
  for(var i = 0; i < someLargeNumber; i++) {}
  console.log('Posting message back to main script');
  postMessage('done');
}
```

Back in you main file

```
<head>
<script>
var myWorker = new Worker("worker.js");
function hello() {
    document.getElementById('hi').innerHTML = "hi";
    myWorker.postMessage('test');
    console.log('Message posted to worker');
}
myWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
  result.textContent = e.data;
  console.log('Worker thread is complete');
}
</script>
```